# Jetpack Compose navigation crashes app when button clicked

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am just playing around with navigation compose and trying to figure out how it works. I read some articles and watch tutorials how to implement it in my app. So I choose the simpliest way to do this, but when I clicked the buttot to navigate to second screen, app crashed and exited. What am I doing wrong?

I am not doing any fancy stuff like bottom navigation, splash screens and etc, just navigate to the second screen.

Here I created navigation's logic
@Composable

```
fun navigationDraft(navController: NavController) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = ScreenNavigation.Home.routeName
    ) {
        composable(route = ScreenNavigation.Home.routeName) {
            Home( navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = ScreenNavigation.DetailedScreen.routeName) {
            DetailedScreen(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I created navigation's route:

```
sealed class ScreenNavigation(var routeName: String, ){
    object Home : ScreenNavigation(routeName = "home")
    object DetailedScreen : ScreenNavigation(routeName = "detailed")
}
```

HomeScreen:

```
@Composable
fun Home(navController: NavController) {
     Button(onClick = {navController.navigate(ScreenNavigation.DetailedScreen.routeName) }) {
   
    }

}
```

Detailed Screen

```
@Composable
fun DetailedScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Scaffold() {
        TopAppBar(elevation = 2.dp, backgroundColor = Color.Magenta) {
            Text(text = "Second Screen With Detail", fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic)
        }
        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            Text(text = "Hi", fontSize = 30.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Users_plofile_kotlinTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                    Home(navController = navController)
              
                    nameViewModel.getUserNameList()
                }
            }
        }
```

The error I have got:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.users_plofile_kotlin, PID: 24321
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1652)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the issue. I created another @Composable MainScreen function  instead of default @Composable Greetings function and put there all routes I would like to use, so my code now a little bit fixed but the main idea is still the same:

This should be instead of @Composable Greeting function

@Composable

```
fun MainScreen(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "home"
    ) {
        composable(route = ScreenNavigation.ButtonToCkeck.route) {
            Home(navController = navController )
        }
        composable(route = ScreenNavigation.DetailedSreen.route) {
            DetailedSreen()
        }
    }
}
```

And put it in the MainAcrivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NavigationAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works smoothly. Also the version of navigation composable is:

```
 implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1")
```

Comment: I found another one solution: the example above is just Hello World example, in my app I am creating the list and want to go to another screen, so you need instead navController using navHostController in constructor, and after that it works. Also I would like to recommend to work on xml instead jetpack. It seems too raw for me in navigation implementation. Yeah, it's fancy and new, but a basic android with a basic navigation is much better. Just IMHO. Don't be mad at me :)